# How to Show TabPage3 when button is Clicked - Visual Studio 2010

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have `Form1`

`Form1` contains `TabControl1` which has 7 TabPages. (TabPage1, TabPage2, ... TabPage7)

I also have `Button1`

How can I show `TabPage4` when I click  on `Button1`?

Answer (score 1):

Handle the `Click` event of the `Button` and, in the event handler, set the `SelectedIndex` or `Selectedtab` property of the `TabControl`.